# Floating point corruption in C multi thread environment

Tags: c, multithreading, floating-point

I'm having a problem with a floating point value returned from additions and multiplications that end up being invalid.

**Background**:
I'm using Speex in a Visual Studio multi-threaded environment. And at a certain point, usualy after 1 or 2 minutes of audio encoding and decoding, my decoded signal becomes entirely Nan. I think my problem is the same as discussed in this thread ([Speex on windows,   audio cutting out](http://lists.xiph.org/pipermail/speex-dev/2009-February/007113.html)), but I dug a little deeper in this issue.

**Situation**:
I modified a part of libspeex to put some debugging code, here is what I have (I've expanded some macros here, I know some parts are redundant).

```
float *mem, *den;     // Arrays of finite float values
float nyi;      // finite float value.
float a1, a2;   // debug test variables.

...

if (!_finite(mem[j]) || !_finite(mem[j+1]))
    printf("Nan\n");       // Does not reach this

a1     = ((mem[j+1])+(float)(den[j])*(float)(nyi));   // a1 == expected value
mem[j] = ((mem[j+1])+(float)(den[j])*(float)(nyi));   // mem[j] == -1.#IND
a2     = ((mem[j+1])+(float)(den[j])*(float)(nyi));   // a2 == expected value

if (!_finite(mem[j]) || !_finite(mem[j+1]))
    printf("Nan\n");          // Program reach this and stops at breakpoint
```

The first strange behaviour is that *a1* and *a2* compute the correct value while *mem[j]* does not. Second strange thing: If I try to re-execute the affectation to *mem[j]* statement (I know it could lead to unexpected results, but it still gives a hint for debugging purpose), then the value affected to *mem[j]* is the expected value: Same as a1 and a2.

I did check the obvious:

- This code portion is mutex protected: There is no way another thread could have corrupted memory.
- All float values are valid, finite, and the result from the addition and multiplication should fall in the range of a float.
- All array indices are within range of their respective arrays.

The problem does not seems to appear if there is no other thread running.

- This thread: the audio decoding thread.
- An audio encoding thread.
- Some network socket threads...

It is part of a large software, but the decoding part is really protected from the rest by proper mutexes.

So it looks as if a context switch occured while in the middle of the float computation, and that it failed to restore the context after. But it's hard to beleive something that bad could happen.

I've heard of floating point inconsistencies when used in multi-thread, but it should only affect the least significant part, not generate a Nan value.

Did anyone ever seen such a behaviour? How did you solve it?

Comment: So these three lines are in the library itself, right? Why are there three lines computing the same thing?

Comment: Why also are you repeating your calculation 3 times?  Couldn't you store it once and assign multiple times?  Is this strictly reproducible? (Does it fail in the same place every time, or does it happen at different times?)

Comment: @Shahbaz The a1 and a2 lines are added by me to debug, and show the non-repeating/strange behaviour.

Comment: @Wug It does not fail at the same iteration every time, takes between 1 and 2 minutes. But it does fail at the same line of code every time it fails.

Comment: @jslap, what is the value of `j`, and the size of `mem` for which the test fails? Also, have you noticed that `den` is not really an array? (or is that a typo when copying to stack overflow?)

Comment: please expand to include the code you're using to protect the critical section, and maybe a little bit about how you're doing multithreading.

Comment: @Shahbaz As I said in the question, all array indices are within range. And, yes, the den variable is a typo, thanks.

Comment: @Wug Tried to expand a little. But it is part of a big software, I can't show everything.

Answer (score 2):

Questions:

- what's up with all the superfluous casts?
- what are the values of `den[j]` and `nyi`?

Those aside, a reasonable possibility is that another computation on the same thread has either overflowed the floating-point stack, or used MMX instructions but failed to issue the `emms` instruction before yielding control (either of these conditions will cause otherwise unobjectionable floating-point computations to produce NaN results).  Start by examining the x87 status word in the failure state to confirm or rule out these possibilities.

The fact that the problem does not occur without multiple threads makes this explanation somewhat less likely, but a corrupt x87 state is by far the most common source of "otherwise unexplicable" NaNs, and should be ruled out first.

Comment: Should I watch the status register before or after the failure happened? I have to watch the exception part? What would be the normal value for the exception bits? 0?

Comment: Check the state of the status register once the failure has occurred.  If the IE and SF bits (0 and 6) are set, then you are looking at stack corruption.  If IE (bit 0) is set but SF is not, then your computation legitimately produced a NaN.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I reproduced the bug again, and the stat register is set 0x0961. So yes, the invalid operation and the stack fault bits are set. So my stack is corrupted. Any idea how to proceed from there?

Comment: Interesting.  FPU state is thread-local, so this shouldn't change depending on whether or not another thread is running (unless your OS is really, truly busted, in which case you would expect to see other failures).  Is there any code that is run only if multithreading is enabled?  The other thing to check is to make sure to build the project with warnings for missing prototypes enabled; calling functions that return a float value without a prototype is  by far the most common source of x87 stack corruption.

Comment: No missing prototypes, anywhere. I chack for the status bits just before the faulty operation, and it is ok. Right after, it sets the two bad bits: IE and SF. The disassembly looks fine. And if I reset IE and SF and repeat the float operation, it gives the right result and does not set IE or SF.

Comment: Does anything on that thread use MMX instructions?  The EMMS instruction needs to be emitted after any MMX use and before any x87 instructions in order to avoid a stack fault.

Comment: Positive, there is no MMX calls from my code. I'm using third party libs, though, may be they use mmx.